# multiple Event wise editable option set in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

how to set multiple event wise "Editable" option "True" or "False" in full calendar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EventObject or event hash](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) that takes several options. One such option is [editable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/editable/).
You can have this property set to some default value and change it for events that you want to behave differently.

Full-calendar allows you to set different behavior for each events based on the options provided as `Event Data` and `Event Rendering`.

Please go through the docs for detailed understanding.